USB drives visible but do not show up in file browser
I have a couple of SanDisk USB drive. I have a dual boot Ubuntu 22 / Windows 10 Lenovo laptop and these USB drives work as expected when booted in Windows, and they also work fine in my MacBook, so it is not an issue with the drives themselves.
The drives are recognised when I plug them in :-
lsusb | grep -i sandisk
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra

sudo dmesg | grep -i sandisk
[ 1232.508559] usb 3-6: Product:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
[ 1233.528479] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access      USB      SanDisk 3.2Gen1 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6

And from sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.32 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk model:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008b1c4

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 30031871 30029824 14.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

But they do not show up in the file browser.
I think that I am missing a driver or something?

No, you are not missing a driver. Ubuntu can work fully with a partition formatted in FAT32. A partition, however, will only be mounted if it is healthy.

@vanadium  As they work fine in other machines/OS, is there anything I can do to work out why Ubuntu does not mount the partitions?

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
